# Hashchain generating using async

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash, lodash, async.js

I'm trying to generate a hashchain using the following code:

```
var async = require('async');
var _ = require('lodash');

var offset = 1e7;

var games = 1e7;  
var game = games;
var serverSeed = '238asd1231hdsad123nds7a182312nbds1';

function loop(cb) {
    var parallel = Math.min(game, 1000);

    var inserts = _.range(parallel).map(function() {
        return function(cb) {
            serverSeed = genGameHash(serverSeed);
            game--;

            query('INSERT INTO `hash` SET `hash` = ' + pool.escape(serverSeed));
        };
    });

    async.parallel(inserts, function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;

        // Clear the current line and move to the beginning.
        var pct = 100 * (games - game) / games;
        console.log('PROGRESS: ' + pct.toFixed(2) + '%')

        if (game > 0){
            loop(cb);
        }else {
            console.log('Done');
            cb();
        }
    });
}

loop(function() {
    console.log('Finished with SEED: ', serverSeed);
});
```

When I run this code it generates a hash chain of 1k hash's, while I'm trying to generate a chain of 1m hash's. It seems like async isn't working properly, but I have no idea why, there are no errors in console, nothing that points out a flaw.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're never calling `cb`, so it will never know that anything is finished and get to the next iteration. What are `genGameHash`, `query` and `pool.escape`, are the asynchronous?

Answer (score 0):

Do you can run it with smaller `games` (about 3000)?
Your parallel function nerver send `done signal` because the `callback` of `inserts item` never trigged. I think `query` function has two pramasters `query(sql: string, callback?: (err, result) => void)` (Typescript style).
I suggest you change your logic and flow like below block code:

```
    var inserts = _.range(parallel).map(function() {
            return function(cb) {
                serverSeed = genGameHash(serverSeed);
                query('INSERT INTO `hash` SET `hash` = ' + pool.escape(serverSeed), function(err, result) {
                  if(result && !err) {
                    game--;
                  }
                  cb(); // remember call the callback
                });
            };
        });
```

In your code, you have used `async.parallel`, I think it is not good idea, too many connection has be open(1m). Recommeded for this case is [parallelLimit](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallelLimit)

Comment: Don't ignore the `err`, better pass it to `cb`.

Comment: @Bergi if you put `err` to `callback` , in case `err !== null` the `parallel` will be stop and break go to `final callback`, it cancel all `waiting querys`. In logic we only care `success case` and control when to stop by `game variable`.